# PyObject_CallMethod returns Null

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I have an image processing application that I am using OpenCV within Python and then have it embedded in Embarcadero C++ XE6 IDE for Windows.

I followed all the great exampled and was able to get the embedded Python code working in the bare application.  However when I try to use numpy (loadImage) I get the following error:

```
<type 'exception.AttributeError'>:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

If I simply return out of the Python function with a True (commented out now) it returns a valid PyObject.  If I try to average the intensity of the pixels with numpy it returns a NULL object.

I am thinking I don't have the imports setup correctly.  The stand-alone Python application works as expected but not when it's embedded into my C++ application.

**Python Code:**

```
import numpy
import cv2

class Camera:      

def __init__(self):
    print 'OpenCV Version:', cv2.__version__

def loadImage(self):
    '''
       Load image from file
    '''
    global img
    img = cv2.imread('cameraImageBlob.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    #return True
    return numpy.average(img)         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dc = Camera()
    print dc.loadImage()
```

**C++ Code:**

```
#include "Python.h"

int main() {
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue, *pClass, *pInstance;

    double dValue;

    // Initilize the Python interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Set runtime paths
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import cv2");

    // Build the name object - create a new reference
    pName = PyString_FromString((char*)"OpenCVTest");

    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if(pModule != NULL) {
        //pDict is a borrowed reference so no DECREF
        pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

        // Get the Camera Class
        pClass = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "Camera");
        if(PyCallable_Check(pClass)) {
           pInstance = PyObject_CallObject(pClass, NULL);
        } else {
           return;
        }

        // Load Image and get intensity
        pValue = PyObject_CallMethod(pInstance, "loadImage", NULL);
        if(pValue == NULL) {
           GetError();
        } else {
           dValue = PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue);
        }
    }

    Py_DecRef(pName);
    Py_DecRef(pModule);
    Py_DecRef(pValue);
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `imread` is not being able to load the image, so it is returning `None`, which is what's causing your error.  Are you sure the image can be found in the path from where you are running?

Comment: Also, you should check that `pInstance` is not NULL after the `PyObject_CallObject` call.

Comment: Thanks Jaime! it was related to the image load/working directory.  It now works correctly after I placed a copy of the image in the root of my .exe